# How can I generate the <abbr> HTML tag from org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I'm trying to migrate my current blogging platform (Pelican) where I wrote the
posts using Markdown to a one based in org-mode (still considering how).

One of the problems that I found is that I have used the `<abbr>` HTML tag in
several of my articles --thanks to the Markdown Extra markup `*[abbr]: definition`
that I could use with Pelican-- but I can not find a way in *org-mode* to export that
tag.

Is there any way to generate this tag from org-mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the simplest way is to define a macro in your orgmode file with:

```
#+MACRO: abbr @@html:<abbr title="$1">$2</abbr>@@
```

You can then add an abbr in your text with:

```
{{{abbr(Definition, abbreviation)}}}
```

---

Edit:

This is probably the better solution: Add a special tag for abbr:

```lisp
(defun org-export-abbr (backend)
  "Replace {abbreviation|description} to <abbr> html text in
current buffer"
  (when (equal backend 'html)
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-buffer)
      (replace-regexp "{\\(.*?\\)|\\(.*?\\)}"
                      "@@html:<abbr title=\"\\2\">\\1</abbr>@@"))))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'org-export-abbr)
```

This will replace occurence of {abbreviation|description} into an abbr tag on HTML export.

Comment: #+HTML does not work in-line. For inlining the format should be `@@html:<abbr>@@` according to http://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-HTML-tags.html#Quoting-HTML-tags

Comment: It is not as nicest as the Markdown Extra solution but it works (if we do what @Juancho mentioned) and I suppose that I could make a snippet to make it easier to use. Thanks!

Comment: See my second solution. Probably a lot more convenient. @Juancho Thx for the correction.

Comment: Yes, is a way better solution and works nicely! Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, I don't know if there is a way to avoid to replace that expression on the SRC, EXAMPLE, LaTeX, blocks, etcetera but I had to make a tweak in the regexp to avoid to replace a Jinja expression like this `{% foo|bar -%}` by an HTML abbr tag in a SRC block. I took the easy way to do the trick: `"{[^%]\\(.*?\\)|\\(.*?\\)}"`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the previous comment with the regexp, the right one is this `"{\\([^%].*?\\)|\\(.*?\\)}"`